# How can i create category page link in cakephp?

Tags: php, html, cakephp-3.0

*How can i create category page link in cakephp?*

```
<?php if(count($cat)>0): foreach($cat as $cat_item): ?>  
<li>  
<a href="<?php Router::url('/', true); ?>category/<?php echo $cat_item['CatModel']['caturl']; ?>">  
    <?php echo $cat_item['CatModel']["catname"];  ?></a>  
</li>  
<?php endforeach; else: ?>  
<p class="no-record"></p>  
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wish to use the HTML helper you can use this.

```
<li>
    <?= $this->Html->link(__($cat_item['CatModel']['catname']), ['controller' => 'Categories', 'action' => 'view', $cat_item['CatModel']['id']]); ?>  
</li>
```

Assuming your category controller is called "CategoriesController.php", and is located in src/Controller

In general, you can use the cake client from the command line to generate models/controllers/views if you follow the cake schema naming convention.

> bin/cake bake template categories

If you wish to see the cake way of doing things. It will generate your view. Also for more information on the HTML helper check out the [CookBook](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/html.html).

Comment: Thanks for your reply Thomsen

Answer (score 1):

You need to do 4 steps :

- Create link in view (as you did)
- Create Route for that link
- Create Function in relevant controller
- Create view for that function.